# Verify contract with bytes constructor argument

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat, etherscan

I am trying to verify my contracts via etherscan and hardhat. Everything seems fine with contracts without constructor arguments. I do it with
`npx hardhat verify ${address} --network goerli`

The problem is with one of my contracts that has `bytes` argument in the constructor. I can't pass bytes in the command line. Hex strings like "\x01\x02\x03\x04" dont work either. Converted to chars doesn't work also.

Is there a way to write script that passes the arrayified variable as constructor argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan)

> When the constructor has a complex argument list, you'll need to write
> a javascript module that exports the argument list. The expected
> format is the same as a constructor list

you should have a file like `arguments.js`

```
module.exports = [
  50,
  "a string argument",
  {
    x: 10,
    y: 5,
  },
  // bytes have to be 0x-prefixed
  "0xabcdef",
];
```

this is arguments for a contract. and in commandline:

```
npx hardhat verify --constructor-args arguments.js DEPLOYED_CONTRACT_ADDRESS
```